# StartPreview fails only on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-camera

We keep getting crash reports that StartPreview failed with the following stack trace. This seems to work just fine when running on other devices. I tried to repro it using a S3 but couldn't. It seems to work just fine.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
at com.myapp.myservice.photo.PhotoCaptureView.surfaceChanged(PhotoCaptureView.java:293)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:621)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:93)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:182)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:864)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2142)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This seems to happen when there is a change in the preview. The runtime exception occurs when calling startPreview.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)  
{  
    if (mCamera == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Surface changed but no current camera!");
        return;
    }

    if (mIsPreviewRunning) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mIsPreviewRunning = false;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged: Failed with IOException", ex);
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();
    mIsPreviewRunning = true;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's on line 293 in PhotoCaptureView.java?

Comment: mCamera.startPreview();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's caused by holder. In surfaceChanged, use `SurfaceHolder sHolder = getHolder();` to check whether `sHolder` equals to `holder`. If not, use `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sHolder);` instead of `mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);` If sHolder equals to holder. You can call `mCamera.stopPreview();` before `mCamera.startPreview();`

Comment: Looks like what you said. When I am trying to use mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sHolder), it is displaying a blank screen. You know anything about this?

Comment: I think it's Samsung's ROM issue. Upgrading your system version may solve this issue.